# Analysis Problem

Tags: analysis

Given that: For any $[a, b]\subset (-\infty,+\infty)$, $f$ is integrable in $[a,b]$, $p>0$, and ${\mid f\mid}^{p}$ is integrable in $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Prove that

$$\lim_{h\to0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\mid {f(x+h)-f(x)}\mid ^{p} dx=0
$$

Comment: What have you attempted yourself?

Comment: Did you intend to include $p \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Yes. Include $$p\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the appendix of [these lecture notes,](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf)  the set of compactly supported functions is dense in $L^p$ also for $0<p<1$. Hence the usual proof applies: the property is obvious if the support of $f$ is bounded, then we approximate $f$ with compactly supported continuous functions and ewe conclude.

Comment: I haven't learnt functional analysis yet. This exercise is in improper integral. So I think there is a method to solve the problem without using functional analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Put $h = \frac 1 n$ and then use Lebegue's dominated converge theorem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/650292)

Comment: @Qwerty: Hints *are* allowed as answers. In fact, the policy on MSE is to use comments only for clarifications and it is accepted to provide hints instead of full answers. (It is true that fewer and fewer people obey these rules - including me -, but it is good for you to know them.) In particular, this means that the above post *does* qualify as an answer.